# JSON data divided by using segmented control

Tags: ios, json, swift3, uisegmentedcontrol

I have some JSON data. The data is like below and I took a segmented control which contains active state and pending state, by using segmented control separate the JSON data. If `order_status = 0` (below JSON data) that will store in pending state, if `order_status = 1` that will store in active state.

I know how to parse JSON but I do not know how to separate the data by using segmented control.

```
{
    "status": "done",
    "order_data": [{


        "price": "1000",
        "qty": "1",
        "total_price": "1000",
        "voucher_id": "NIL",
        "purchase_id": "1005",
        "purchase_on": "NIL",
        "validity": "30 days from the date of purchase",
        "left_day": "NIL",
        "order_status": 0
    }, {

        "price": "3000",
        "qty": "1",
        "total_price": "3000",
        "voucher_id": "NIL",
        "purchase_id": "10070",
        "purchase_on": "NIL",
        "validity": "30 days from the date of purchase",
        "left_day": "NIL",
        "order_status": 1
    }, {


        "price": "3000",
        "qty": "1",
        "total_price": "3000",
        "voucher_id": "NIL",
        "purchase_id": "1076767",
        "purchase_on": "NIL",
        "validity": "30 days from the date of purchase",
        "left_day": "NIL",
        "order_status": 1
    }]
}
```

Comment: Create two different arrays and store active state values in one array and pending state values in another array.

Comment: how to take data from json data ,when only order status = 1

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose that your data is in a variable named as jsonData, then firstly parse the json data and get two array of dictionary, one for pending state data and another one for active state data, then use both of the dictionary for segment control.

```
if let orderData = jsonData["order_data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
let pendingStateData = orderData.filter({ (newOrder) -> Bool in
    return (newOrder["order_status"] as? Int) == 0
})

let activeStateData = orderData.filter({ (newOrder) -> Bool in
    return (newOrder["order_status"] as? Int) == 1
})
}
```

So, using these filter you can filter the data and can get the desired filter data according to you.